# Who are the masters that are being held in jail?

Tags: historys-strongest-disciple-kenichi

In History Strongest Disciple Kenichi, the masters of Ryozanpaku and the One Shadow Nine Fists are about to have an all-out war. They mention that there are 2 masters trapped in a jail and that they won't get out because of their pride. Who are these two masters and in which manga episode where they defeated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're talking about:

[image]

[Alexander Gaidar](http://kenichi.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_Gaidar)  and

[image]

[Diego Carlo](http://kenichi.wikia.com/wiki/Diego_Carlo), both members of the One Shadow Nine Fists and incarcerated at the ["Big Lock"](http://kenichi.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Lock). Alexander was defeated in [Battle 304](http://kenichi.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_304) and Diego was defeated in [Battle 333](http://kenichi.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_333).

Comment: Please can you add in which manga chapter they were defeated?

Comment: @Washu Sorry, missed that part of your question.